# Как правильно объявлять и переназначать переменную js?

Tags: javascript, переменные

```
if (i < 15) {
    var k = 0;
} else if (i >=10 && i <= 20) {
    k = 1;
} else if (i >= 20) {
    k = 2;
}
```

Т.е. сначала мы объявляем с директивой `var`, а потом когда присваиваем переменной новое значение, то можно без `var`?

Comment: Нынче уже используют  `let` и `const`

Comment: А как мне вынести let k=2 за условие if? Если я правильно понял вне условия она не будет объявлена?

Comment: Вывести можете функцией `alert(k);` Тут подробно про объявление переменных - https://learn.javascript.ru/let-const

Comment: @ThisMan человек спросил про var

Comment: @Sublihim, поэтому я оставил комментарий, а не ответ

Answer (score 3):

Есть такое понятие, как "[Hoisting](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp)".

Неважно, где в функции Вы объявляете переменную, это эквивалентно следующему:

```
var k;
if (i < 15) {
    k = 0;
} else if (i >=10 && i <= 20) {
    k = 1;
} else if (i >= 20) {
    k = 2;
}
```

Объявление переменной **всплывает** к началу функции на этапе интерпретации..

Comment: только при использовании `var`. Что интересно, в спецификации определение hoisting применяется только к функциям, но не к объявлениям переменных

Comment: Определение функций(с помощью `function`) ведёт себя так же, да. `let`/`const` - конструкции с блочной областью видимости и в вопросе не фигурировали.

Comment: По поводу спецификации, вижу в `ecma-262` "13.7.5.9 Runtime Semantics: BindingInitialization"

Comment: Там не совсем про всплытие переменных :) Обрати внимание, что HoistableDeclaration раскрывается только как определение функции или генератора, а в описании самого [_statement **var**_](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-variable-statement) хоистинг не упоминается.

Comment: Это 7.0 спека, в старой было про `var`. Вот ещё - `Var variables are created when their containing Lexical Environment is instantiated and are initialized to undefined when created`. Таким образом, `VariableDeclaration` не является `HoistableDeclaration`, однако поведение таки весьма похоже =)

Comment: Ну я как раз это и имел ввиду :-) _в старой было про var_ - в шестой уже точно не было.

Comment: @vp_arth киньте ссылку на спеку )

Comment: @stack-it [Вот тут](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) обе

Answer (score -1):

```
var k;//просто объявили переменную k

if (i < 15) {
    k = 0;
} else if (i >=10 && i <= 20) {
    k = 1;
} else if (i >= 20) {
    k = 2;
}
```

Comment: Сначала объявили переменную, затем, просто переопределяете уже созданную переменную.